# Oracle TO_DATE function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, to-date

I always thought that to_date function string and date format should match. Why is the below statement working fine?

```
select TO_DATE('20151014','yyyy-mm-dd') from dual;
```

Is oracle now ignoring the special characters before converting string to date?

This is in Oracle 11g.

Comment: Also try with '2015/10/14'.

Comment: Yeah, that works too.. But why is the below statement working?   select TO_DATE('2015/10$14','yyyy--%-mm-dd') from dual;

Answer (score 5):

I found this interesting and asked the Google, which told me that basically when formats don't match Oracle tries it's hardest to make it work:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9522299800346947976

http://www.oracledba.co.uk/tips/dates_8i.htm

You can use the 'FX' format string to make it match exactly:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#r18c1-t65

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216

You learn something new every day!  Thanks for asking this!

Comment: Very interesting...  I always thought that Oracle was very rigid with date formatting, compared to other RDBMSs.  I guess you just have to know how to push its buttons.

Comment: Same here.  Very interesting.

Comment: I have also noticed this when I did something like 10-14-2015 when the date format actually called for 10/14/2015. This is good to know.